# Show vertical scrollbar within a TextWrapping TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, scrollbar, word-wrap

I have an WPF `UserControl`. Within, I have a `Grid` which contains only a row with a few columns.
There is a `TextBox` which I has its `TextWrapping` set to `Wrap` using an style:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And the `Grid`:

```
<Grid Height="auto" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" 
                 Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="5"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Text}"
                 Foreground="{Binding Path=ForegroundColor}">
        </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

What happens is that the vertical scroll bar is never shown. Instead, the text is cut off vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your row as well as your column definition for the `TextBox` [use `Auto` as size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks):

> If a child element is added to a column within a Grid, and the column has its `Width` property set to `Auto`, the **child will be measured without restrictions**. This behavior can prevent horizontal scroll bars from displaying if a `ScrollViewer` is being used, as the child element is measured as unbounded. For purposes of display, **the child is clipped rather than scrolled**.

This is exactly what happens in your case. Through the unbounded width, the `TextBox` expands horizontally until it fits its content and that is way beyond the available (visible) space, so the rest is cut off. The same applies to the unbounded height, in case you fixed the width only. Consequently, all the content technically fits in and no scrollbars are shown.

You should use star sizing in this case to size the `TextBox` in the [remaining space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks).

> Columns and rows that are defined within a Grid can take advantage of Star sizing to distribute remaining space proportionally.

This way, its size is bounded by the remaining space and if there is not enough space available for the whole text, the scollbars are shown. Here I just replaced `Auto` sizes with `*` which works:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Of course, you have to transfer this to fit your layout requirements.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your detailed explaination. In my case for some circumstances I need that columndefinition to be auto. Also one more thing, I need also TextBox to fit all the vertical space of the grid column so I have used VerticalAlignment="Stretch" but it is not working. Do you know why? The textbox incresase vertically dynamically so I need to fit all the vertical space of the grid column.

Comment: Regarding to my previous comment, as you said, specifying RowDefinition Height = "*", star instead of auto works. in my case it is not necessary to specify star for columndefinition width since I am only interested in the vertical scrollbar and fit to column height.